# How can i return unique_ptr with pointer function?

Tags: c++

i don't understand fully this problem. This is my function and i need return class with unique_ptr how can i this?

my list:

`std::list<std::unique_ptr<Maths> > l_MathsList;`

my function

```
Maths* Maths2::FindMathsID(int iID)
{
    auto mpClass= std::unique_ptr<Maths>();
    for (auto&& it : l_MathsList)
    {
        if (iter->IsMy(iID)) { 
            mpClass = std::move(it); 
            }
            break; 
        }
    }
    return mpClass; // compiler error
```

Comment: You've declared a function which returns a `Maths*` and then you've elected to return a `std::unique_ptr`. The compile error likely tells you as much. Either change the return type or quit making a smart pointer.

Comment: @SilvioMayolo thanks for your comment! Can u give example for return type? Compiler error: `cannot convert 'std::unique_ptr<MathFuncs::Maths>' to 'MathFuncs::MathFuncs*' in return`

Comment: If you intend to return a `unique_ptr`, then the return type should be `std::unique_ptr<Maths>`. But note that, once you've called this function once, some prefix of the list `l_MathsList` (which I presume is an instance variable) will be left empty and therefore inaccessible.

Comment: @SilvioMayolo i need this but i wish using smart ptr working func:
`
Maths * mClass= NULL;
 for (auto it = l_MathsList.cbegin(); it != l_MathsList.cend(); it++) {
  if ((*it)->IsMy(iID)) { 
   mClass= *iter; 
   if ( (parameter2)!= NULL) { 
    mClass->ReCalc(parameter2);
   }
   break; 
  }
 }
 return mClass;
`

Comment: You set `rtClass` but return `mpClass`?

Comment: @Galik no, this is my text mistake, so sorry

Comment: If the requirement is to "return a ...", then declare your function to so just that. Work on figuring out how to accomplice the task and ... question the task.

Comment: Also your `break;` happens the first time round the loop regardless if `iID` is found.

Comment: Deducing functional requirements from buggy code is an exercise in futility. I do not see how this question could be useful to future visitors unless the functional requirements are added as text (preferably before the code).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably just want to return a non-owning pointer to the collection element right?

In that case just use `.get()`:

```
Maths* Maths2::FindMathsID(int iID)
{
    for (auto& it : l_MathsList)
    {
        if (it->IsMy(iID))
          return it.get();
    }
    return nullptr;
}
```